# How to FAST transfer files from server to Android phone with Java?

Tags: java, android, sockets, server

I'm building an Android app that requires some files sent to it from our server. I've implemented both the Server Socket in Java and the Android socket client and tested it, but the transfer is too slow.

```
FILE SIZE: 5 MB
TRANSFER TIME: 15.3 seconds
```

So the server is set up on my own PC, I use port forwarding so I can be able to connect to it from any network. If you think it's relevant, here is a speed test of my network: http://www.speedtest.net/my-result/3965566858

Now the server code:

```
BufferedInputStream musicData = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File("fileSrc")));

byte[] data = new byte[8192];
int count = 0;

while ((count = musicData.read(data)) > 0) {
  outStreamMusic.write(data, 0, count);
}
```

Client code:

```
InputStream inStream = socketClient.getInputStream();
byte[] data = new byte[8192];
int count = 0;

while ((count = inStream.read(data)) > 0) {
      tempFile.write(data, 0, count);
}
```

So this will open the file, parse it and send bytes until there's nothing else to send. I'm pretty sure this can be done faster but I have no idea how. The Android client just opens a socket to my ip/port and reads data from it. Any idea how to make this faster?

Comment: You can play around with the 8192 but that's mostly it (nio channels is the alternative but that's probably not faster either). `0` is btw a legal value for `read()` to return even though there is more to come. I'd also get rid of the `BufferedInputStream` since you have your own buffer and another one won't help. How does the client code look like?

Comment: Is the phone on wifi or cellular?  If on cellular this is probably to be expected-  your limiting factor is latency, not throughput.  Setting up the connection on cellular takes a lot of time.

Comment: Another thought-  are you using a buffered file writer, or unbuffered?  If unbuffered, that's potentially the problem.  Try commenting out the write to limit it to just the transfer time, isolate the problem.

Comment: I've never tested it on cellular, only wi-fi. Probably that's even slower..

Comment: @GabeSechan a buffered reader or writer is pointless when you do it with your own `byte[]` buffer, they only make sense if you read or write small bits all the time.

Comment: I write the file on Android using BufferedOutputStream class.

Comment: @zapl Buffering always makes sense, it will batch writes together and write it with the correct optimized size for your disk sector size.

Comment: @GabeSechan A buffered output stream can't do that. All it does is gather data until it is full then it does `write(byte[] bigChunk)`. But that's just another arbitrarily sized buffer and above code does already the same. Java streams just push data into OS level caches which then gets written in batches. Buffered streams are also not asynchronous, so the system isn't taking data in appropriate chunks from there.

Answer (score -1):

IF you want your android device to read data from a server, its best done using the android AsynTask
and implement the doInBackground method. 
This way you can establish a connection to your server using HttpClient of the org.apache library and issue a request and receive a response in which your can read it through from an inputStream.

```
public String doInBackground()
{
  DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
  HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("www.yourserverip.com");
  HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
  HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
  BufferReader reader = new BufferReader(new InputStreamReader(entity.getContent()));'
  while(reader.readLine!=null)
  {
    //Read Something    
    //read Your data  
  }
 /*Note this is just a basic use of httpClient*/
 /*Also if its a file you really might not use the bufferedReader*/
}
```

First Of all I really hope i understand your question and what you really want to achieve.

Comment: I know how to read from the server. See edit on question. I just think 15 seconds for 5 MB is too slow and I was wondering if my method is bad and if there's anything I can do to make it faster.

Comment: He's talking about transferring data via socket, not an HTTP request.  And he's not asking for how to do it on Android, he's asking why things are so slow, which this doesn't really address.